# cast from integer (addr) into pointer to member function c++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, member-functions

I'm trying to cast an integer that contains an address of an member function into a pointer to a member function, and then, calling the function. Something like that:

```
typedef void (A::*func)(uint8_t, uint8_t);


void A::method()
{
    uint32_t addr = .....;    //absolute addr of member funtion 

    func ptr = (func)(addr);           //error 

    this->*(func)(1, 0);               //error
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Assuming that the member function is not static, it also takes an `A*` argument (as the first argument). So attempting to call it with only those two `uint8_t` arguments is erroneous to begin with.

Comment: Update: ptr is not declared inside method. Ptr is a member variable of A!

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by `this->*(func)`? If anything, it should be `this->*(ptr)`. But please read my previous comment on invoking your member function this way. In addition, have you considered the standard way of doing it, i.e., using a virtual function? Feels like you're possibly trying to reinvent the wheel here a bit.

Comment: i learned that a possible way to call a function non-static through a pointer is using an instance of the class. In this case, i'm using this! I already used that in other example and it works perfectly. My first problem here is related with the cast from integer (containing an addr) into a pointer to a member class, not the calling convention.

Comment: yes, you are right about this*->(ptr)! but about the cast?

Comment: I think you need to use `std::bind`.

Comment: A pointer to member function is more than a raw address. It has information about how to adjust the `this` pointer so that you can call the function on an object of a type that's derived from the declared class type of the pointer. When you call through a pointer to member function the compiler generates code that expects that information to be there, and there's no way that a cast of an integer value can supply that information.